# What are some Best CSS Practices, Do you Re-use previous CSS? How about Frameworks?

Tags: css

I'm compiling Great Ideas how to optimize and improve your CSS. What are your best practices that you would like to share? Do you use frameworks? Do you re-use your CSS? Do you document your CSS?

Please share. Thanks!

Additional Question,

How do you generated IDs and Class in naming your markups... are they generic or specific? Are most of your project has a similar class and ids?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the results of your research? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to use the 960 grid system, it works like a champ.  Other than that, the only CSS I normally reuse are stuff I use on forms.

http://960.gs/

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of the [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) framework:

> Blueprint is a CSS framework, which
>   aims to cut down on your development
>   time. It gives you a solid foundation
>   to build your project on top of, with
>   an easy-to-use grid, sensible
>   typography, useful plugins, and even a
>   stylesheet for printing.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own CSS file that I re-use and basically it has only this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    color: #000;
    font: 14px/20px Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}


/*** COMMON ELEMENTS
**************************************/

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

blockquote {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

/*** 
**************************************/
```

The rest I like to change on the fly since every project/site is different.

As for other things, you can follow this short list - [6 Easy Tips To Make Your CSS Efficient](http://karinne.net/2008/04/02/6-easy-tips-to-make-your-css-efficient/)

Hope this helps

Comment: cool, I also used this type of approach...

Comment: I think the main thing is to definitely "try" different methods. If they work for you, that's great! If not, take what you like and make your own ;)

Comment: This is the right idea. I would call your CSS file a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read Steve Souders's book "[Even Faster Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522304)." There's at least one chapter in there that deals with the performance aspects of CSS selectors. It may surprise you which kinds of selectors are "high performance" and which are not - it's completely unintuitive.